# prevent page from web browser

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am working in rails and I am facing a problem, I have a page where I am using iFrame to open a another page in iFrame. Its working fine, but I want which page am opening in iFrame it should not be open in browser. As when I copied the link and open in another tab it opens I want to prevent that page and want that page opens in iFrame only.

Is there any way to prevent this ? in any language either rails or javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if ( !window.parent ) return false`

Comment: its not working.. I want to prevent that page or redirect to root url when any one try to open that link directly in browser.